# String and [a] instances

Tags: haskell, instance, typeclass

As an exercise, I decided to implement a `Blank` type class in Haskell (where `blank` is true when empty, `False`, or a `String` of only whitespace). I started, simply, as one might with:

```
class Blank a where
  blank :: a -> Bool

instance Blank Bool where
  blank = not

instance Blank [a] where
  blank = null
```

When I went to implement the `String` instance:

```
instance Blank String where
  blank [] = True
  blank (' ':xs) = blank xs
  blank ('\t':xs) = blank xs
  blank ('\n':xs) = blank xs
  blank ('\r':xs) = blank xs
  blank _ = False
```

I was greeted with the error:

```
Illegal instance declaration for `Blank String'
  (All instance types must be of the form (T t1 ... tn)
   where T is not a synonym.
   Use -XTypeSynonymInstances if you want to disable this.)
In the instance declaration for `Blank String'
```

I'm pretty sure it's because `[a]` and `String` are redundant, i.e. `String` (`[Char]`) is a more specific instance of `[a]`.

Is there a way get around this and define a more specific instance (i.e. `[Char]`)?

Comment: This is generally "not done" in Haskell; if you write `instance Blank [a] where blank = null` you expect this to hold for *all* `[a]`, so also for `String`. You can wrap `String` in a [`newtype`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Newtype) for which `Blank` behaves differently, instead.

Comment: For an example of this, see [`ZipList a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:ZipList): it's a type containing exactly one `[a]` and nothing more, just to give an alternative `Applicative` instance for lists to the already-defined `instance Applicative []`.

Comment: Alternatively -- I think this makes sense in your case -- you could go for `instance Blank a => Blank [a] where blank = all blank`, and then define `instance Blank Char where blank = isSpace` :)

Comment: This will then define `"   \r"` to be blank, but also `[False, False, False]` or even `[" \t", "\n\n"]` (why?)

Comment: (For the record, I've voted to close because the question is too broad -- the OP wants to do something that you *shouldn't* do in Haskell, and is asking for a workaround, on which opinions will definitely differ; as I've written in these comments, there are multiple ways to do different, better things.)

Answer (score 1):

There's a standard trick to achieve what you want in an elegant way.
If you think about what you want to do you should remember one standard and very used class that uses this: `Show`.

Maybe you never thought about how `show [1,2,3] == "[1, 2, 3]"` while `show "hello" == "\"hello\""`, yet the problem is the same. The way in which this is resolved is by adding a `showList :: [a] -> ShowS` operation to the `Show` class, adding a default definition for it, and then provide an instance for generic lists.

In your case you want something like:

```
import Data.Char(isSpace)

class Blank a where
  blank :: a -> Bool
  blankList :: [a] -> Bool
  blankList = null

instance Blank a => Blank [a] where
  blank = blankList

instance Blank Char where
  blank = isSpace

  blankList [] = True
  blankList (' ':xs) = blankList xs
  blankList ('\t':xs) = blankList xs
  blankList ('\n':xs) = blankList xs
  blankList ('\r':xs) = blankList xs
  blankList _ = False
```

In this way whenever you call `blank` over a list the corresponding `blankList` method is called. The method used is the one provided by the instance of the *elements* of the list, and hence the `Char` instance can define `blankList` to return `True` when the list is non-empty but contains only spaces etc while other instances can simply use the default implementation of `null`.

The downside of this implementation is that you have to put the operations for `String`s into the instance for `Char`. However there is no way around it: in Haskell 98/2010 you can have only one instance for type constructor and class so once you define a `Blank [a]` instance you cannot have other instances using `[]`, which include `String`.

Replacing the instance for `Blank [a]` with an instance for `Blank a => Blank [a]` allows you to define only one instance for `[]` *but* its behaviour changes depending on the instance for `Blank a` and thus you can special case `String`.

---

An alternative solution is to simply *not* handle `String`s at all, as already said. You can always define:

```
newtype MyString = MyString String
```

and then use `MyString` in place of `String`.

Comment: This is fairly horrifying for `Show`, and not, IMO, a good design in general. I think Morris's [approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31724714/string-and-a-instances#comment51386470_31724714) is saner for this purpose.

Comment: @dfeuer It depends. In this simple case it is viable, but you may want to use something that cannot be reduce to `all blank` and a custom definition for `blank` in which case you need a more general approach like this one. I don't find it horrifying. Sure, maybe it's not so elegant however it gets the job done, doesn't require you to write a lot of code for the "default cases", it doesn't need any extension enabled. Can you point out anything wrong/really bad about it?